# React redux loging user in if the registration is successful

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm new to react, and i'm pretty sure this is a trivial problem, but i couldn't find the solution to it. My question is:

**How** do i do another dispatch to my login after my registration dispatch is complete?

I have my dispatch function for my register form like this.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  onSubmit: (username, password, email) => {
    dispatch(register(username, password, email))
  }
});
```

My login dispatch

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  onSubmit: (username, password) => {
    dispatch(login(username, password))
  }
})
```

All i want is to login my user after it registers.

Answer (score 0):

Have your first action changing a field in your store (let's say `isRegistered`), then use `mapStateToProps` to check if `isRegistered` is `true`, and call your second action if it is.